# Handle an Option in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

I have an engine that would like to be a single tenant but with an option to handle multi-tenancy. Is there a better way I could handle this? or is the example below the acceptable way?

```
def index
  if defined?multi_tenant_setting
    @script_extensions = Script::Extension.where(org_id: current_user.org_id)
  else
    @script_extensions = Script::Extension.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one good read over here https://rubygarage.org/blog/separating-features-in-a-multi-tenant-saas-app

**Generate Tenant, Feature, and Subscription models**

rails g model Tenant name:string subdomain:string

rails g model Feature name:string

rails g model Subscription  tenant:references feature:references

rake db:migrate

**Modify the Tenant model app/models/tenant.rb**

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :features, through: :subscriptions
end
```

**Modify the Feature model app/models/feature.rb**

```
class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :tenants, through: :subscriptions
end
```

**Modify the Subscription model app/models/subscription.rb**

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

**Create a new file app/models/feature_toggle.rb with the class FeatureToggle**

```
class FeatureToggle
  def initialize
    @tenant_features = []
  end

  def for(tenant)
    @tenant_features = tenant.features.pluck(:name) if tenant
  end

  def on?(feature_name)
    @tenant_features.include?(feature_name)
  end
end
```

**Modify app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :current_tenant
  helper_method :feature_toggle

  def current_tenant
    @current_tenant ||= Tenant.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  end

  def feature_toggle
    @feature_toggle ||= FeatureToggle.new.tap do |ft|
      ft.for current_tenant
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this will get me in the right direction. Up-voted for bonus b/c stuck on a multi-tenancy plugin. Much appreciated :)